# Linting is not Working after April Update in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-2.7, visual-studio-code

After the April Update of Visual Studio Code, I am not able to Lint any of my python files. I have pylint and pep8 installed and made the following changes to the user.json

```
{
"window.zoomLevel": 0,
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\windows\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\Python27",
"python.linting.pep8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintPath": "C:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\pylint",
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true
```

}

Any leads of how I can enable pylint here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with **PHP IntelliSense**. VS Code was using the wrong php version (5.6) regardless that "$ which php" was giving me the right one (the latest 7.0). I tried changing the symlinks, didn't work. Apparently re-installing the extension did the trick.